# UITextView - set width - allow scrolling up and down - wrap text to width

Tags: iphone, uitextview

Basically I want to have a UITextView - I want it to scroll up and down (ie: I set a height and width, and if the text overflows this then the contentSize is bigger than the frame).

But, I don't want it to get wider. At the moment its scrolling left-to-right. All I want is for it to scroll up and down.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since UITextField inherits from UIScrollView, you should be able to do something like this:

```
myTextField.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,500);
```

This will prevent side scrolling.